# How to inline input and glyph icon in table cell in bootstrap3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot get my glyph icon in one line with input in bootstrap3. How can I do it please, I tried many classes, but evidently none of them worked.. The glyphicon is still displayed on another line , the input is too long. It works only if I set manually width of input, and that is not the best way..

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="search-header">Legend:</td>
    <td>
        <div class="row-fluid form-inline">
            <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputSmall"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: just change `row-fluid` to `row` ... row-fluid isnt available anymore and add a div with form-group inner of the row-div

Comment: It does not work for me. It shrinks input a bit, glyph still on another line and both elements pushed a bit to the left.

Answer (score 4):

One solution could be:

```
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td class="search-header">Legend:</td>
      <td>    
       <div class="col-lg-12 input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSmall">
         <a class="input-group-addon" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

You may also check the official documentation of [Input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're looking to append an icon at the end of a small input, within a table cell.  This should be done as a button, and the Bootstrap 3 code would be as follows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="search-header">Legend:</td>
    <td><div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputSmall">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note that if you want to control the width of this element group you'll need to wrap it in a DIV and apply the appropriate class for whatever width you desire.

UPDATE: [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZksYU/1/)

Comment: This was the answer in my case. Cheers Phil